# Is there a way to use a different property name than what's in my JSON?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, javascript-framework, ember-data

I have the following JSON (simple example):

```
{
  id:        101,
  firstName: "John",
  surname:   "Doe"
}
```

But I want my model to use `lastName` instead of `surname`. Something like this, maybe:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName:  DS.attr('string', { key: 'surname' })
});
```

I could swear I saw something somewhere showing how to do this, but for the life of me, couldn't find it. I also didn't find anything obvious in the ember-data source.

I've tried setting `key`, `name`, `id`, `alias`, and `map` in the attribute options, but none seem to do the trick. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this through [The REST Adapter](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/). The documentation includes an example for mapping "*irregular keys*" under [Underscored Attribute Names](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_underscored-attribute-names):

> Irregular keys can be mapped on the adapter. If the JSON has a key of `lastNameOfPerson`, and the desired attribute name is simply `lastName`, inform the adapter:
>
> ```
> App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
>   lastName: DS.attr('string')
> });
> DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Person', {
>   lastName: { key: 'lastNameOfPerson' }
> });
> ```

In your case:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Person', {
    lastName: { key: 'surname' }
});
```

May also be worth noting that Ember is expecting the JSON to have `first_name` while the model has `firstName`. So, that may also need to be *adapted* explicitly.